# How to flatten a dynamodb item having nested map in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have to write a utility function which reads a dynamodb item and returns a flattened version of that record.

Sample Item

```
const data={
  "node": {
    "S": "someKey"
  },
  "payload": {
    "M": {
      "name": {
        "S": "some_name"
      },
      "phone": {
        "M": {
          "0": {
            "S": "+126526562562"
          },
          "1": {
            "S": "+126512651652"
          }
        }
      },
      "country": {
        "S": "US"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the sample utility function .

```
const utility = (result, field) => {

  const mapping = result[field];
  const { M: data } = mapping;

  const fieldTypes = ['N','S','M'];
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object
      .keys(data)
      .map((key) => ({ fieldType: Object.keys(data[key]).shift(), key }))
      .filter((o) => fieldTypes.includes(o.fieldType))
      .map((o) => [o.key, data[o.key][o.fieldType]]),
  );
};

console.log(flattenMap(data,'payload'))
```

This function works fine if there are no maps inside payload. For example, if I remove the phone attribute from dynamodb item , then I get `{ name: 'some_name', country: 'US' }` which is correct but with `phone`, I get -

```
{
  name: 'some_name',
  phone: { '0': { S: '+126526562562' }, '1': { S: '+126512651652' } },
  country: 'US'
}
```

whereas, what I expect is

```
{
  name: 'some_name',
  phone: { '0':'+126526562562' }, '1': '+126512651652' },
  country: 'US'
}
```

What more do I need to add here so that I get the expected response even with a nested map inside payload.

Answer (score 1):

**The easy way:** use the [SDK v3 DynamoDB utilities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_util_dynamodb.html) to handle conversions:

```js
import { convertToNative } from '@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb';
const converted = convertToNative(payload)
```

**If you insist on DIY:**  use recursion to deal with arbitrary nesting. The `utility` function's logic should be invoked recursively for every value in the payload that is a DynamoDB "map" such as `{ S: '+126526562562' }`.

Values are DynamoDB "maps" if they are key-value pairs with keys of `['N','S','M']`:

```js
if (val.constructor === Object && Object.keys(val).every(k => fieldTypes.includes(k))) {
  // val is a DynamoDB map, call the function recursively on val
}
```